# How to make this email validation regex from regular-expressions.info work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1) led me to [this website](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) which have a bunch of explanation on email validation. The last regex seems the most *accurate* and recommended. I've searched SO for this regex but the implementations I found slightly differ.

I would like to test the following regex provided on the website with my current set of emails and make some tests.

I tried to make the title and this question as precise as possible (for you and the search engines), feel free to suggest edits.

The regex in question is the following:

```
\A(?=[a-z0-9@.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]{6,254}\z)
 (?=[a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]{1,64}@)
 [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
@ (?:(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+
  (?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\z)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z
```

I escaped the `/` characters but it still doesn't seem to work for some reason.

My goal is to use this regex like so:

```
const regexEmail = new RegExp("...")
```

I created a **sandbox** for this regex available on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OTHR0o/1/), but the email address is not found.

I am no pro at regex and usually get only pre made stuff. The help of this community is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove all `\A` and `\z` from your regex, which denote the start and end of a string in Python, yet equate to the literal characters `A` and `z` in JavaScript.

[image: Python]
[image: JavaScript]

Removing these shows the regex working as expected [on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/c6kw4d/1) and in the following:

```js
const email = "ragedog@hotmail.com";
const regex = new RegExp("(?=[a-z0-9@.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]{6,254})(?=[a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]{1,64}@)[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63})[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", "gm");

console.log(regex.test(email));
```

Comment: `\z` does not mean the end of string in Python. It is `\Z` in Python that matches the end of string.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm very glad you stopped by. I didn't see we could switch between languages on the side. I also thought Regex expressions were universal.

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your `RegExp` on a single line, since your actual regular expression contains unescaped backticks (which means you can't use a multi-line string).

```js
const regexEmail = new RegExp("\A(?=[a-z0-9@.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]{6,254}\z)(?=[a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]{1,64}@)[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\z)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z");

console.log(regexEmail);
```